# String comparison in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, string, if-statement, comparison

I have a rest api which return True, False and "". Which i receive this in my requests.content I get the type as byte. I convert them to string and then try to compare. But the last else block executes leaving behind the first and second.

```
import requests
headers = {'Accept': '*/*'}
response = requests.get('http://{IP}/status', headers=headers)
status = response.content
status = str(status)
print(status)
# status returns "True", "False", ""
if (status == "True"):
    print ('Admin approved this request')
elif (status == "False"):
    print ('Admin disapproved this request')
else:
    print ('No response from admin')
```

Getting :- 'No response from admin'
In all the cases

Answer (score 1):

`response.content` is an object of type `bytes`.

Try calling `decode()` on `response.content` instead of casting to a `str` type.

For example if the content of the response is encoded in utf-8 then decode using utf-8:

```
status = response.content.decode('utf-8')
```

When casting a `bytes` object to a `str` type, the resulting string will be prefixed with `"b'"`.

This is why the last `else` block in the code you've supplied always executes. The variable `status` will always be prefixed with `"b'"` (ie. `"b'True'"`, `"b'False'"` or `"b''"`) and the equality comparisons will always evaluate to `False`.

Answer (score 1):

Double check the format of your response. If it's in something like JSON, you'll likely need to access the actual response ("True", "False", "") as a key/value pair.

Also, you can simply use `response.text` to get a string using UTF-8 encoding, instead of converting `response.content` to a string.
https://realpython.com/python-requests/#content